# JavaScript error when creating custom object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am finding that when I call record.create() then sometimes it succeeds, and at other times it throws an error saying that no such method exists, even though record object has its properties set appropriately.

Am I using create method incorrectly? **May be I am missing something about JavaScript custom object syntax.**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var record = {
        RecordID : null,
        CustomerID : null,
        CompanyID : null,

        create : function() {
            var obj = new Object();

            obj.RecordID = "";
            obj.CustomerID = "";
           return obj;
        }
    };

   function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) {
 {
 //*******SUCCEEDS********
 record = record.create()
 }

       function RadGrid1_RowSelected(sender, args) {

        currentRowIndex = args.get_gridDataItem().get_element().rowIndex;

        var dataItem = args.get_gridDataItem().get_dataItem();
        recordId = dataItem["Record_ID"];
        if (tableView.get_selectedItems().length == 1) {
            record = record.create();
            record.RecordID = dataItem["Record_ID"];
            record.CustomerID = dataItem["Customer_ID"];
            setValues();

        }
        else if (tableView.get_selectedItems().length > 1) {
            record= record.create();//****FAILS ALWAYS even when record object has non-null properties*******
        }

        if ($.inArray(recordId, recordIds) == -1) {
            recordIds.push(recordId);
        }
    }

</script>
```

**UPDATE :** This is what worked for me.
*Instead of using the create method* on 'record' global object, I ended up using a simple approach. Just call a custom method 'resetRecord' everytime I wanted to call the create( ) method on record object. That way I have no errors and my logic works perfectly.

```
    function resetRecord() {
        record.RecordID = "";
        record.CustomerID = "";
        record.CompanyID = "";      
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling the create function on an object you got with create ? This object doesn't have the create function... So if you execute the same line again, it will fail.

Comment: The above code will never fail. Yet maybe you are trying to do something like `record.create().create()`?

Comment: Hi All- I have updated my script. So it succeeds in pagelaod event, but fails later on in RadGrid1_RowSelected event . Look at my comment marked with asteriks.

Comment: @dystroy - Yes. Why is the create function lost? Is there a way to preserve it.

Answer (score 3):

It won't work after the first call because you are overwriting the `record` object. This will destroy any `create()` method as the object returned does not have this method/property.

For you update, variables have function level scope. You are using the global `record` inside of `RadGrid1_RowSelected`.

I'm not entirely sure what you are doing but this will get you past your first problem.

```
function RadGrid1_RowSelected(sender, args) {
        var newRecord;

        currentRowIndex = args.get_gridDataItem().get_element().rowIndex;

        var dataItem = args.get_gridDataItem().get_dataItem();
        recordId = dataItem["Record_ID"];
        if (tableView.get_selectedItems().length == 1) {
            record = record.create();
            record.RecordID = dataItem["Record_ID"];
            record.CustomerID = dataItem["Customer_ID"];
            setValues();

        }
        else if (tableView.get_selectedItems().length > 1) {
            newRecord= record.create();//****FAILS ALWAYS even when record object has non-null properties*******
        }

        if ($.inArray(recordId, recordIds) == -1) {
            recordIds.push(recordId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So how can I preserve the create method. The idea is to set it to a new record object.

Comment: Could you please give some sample code? I tried this: var r = record.create(); r = record;, BUT it still failed.

Comment: @Sunil I've updated my answer. I strongly suggest spending some time studying the fundamentals of javascript before continuing.

Comment: @ryan- Your code throws the same error 'Object doesn't support this property or method' at newRecord =  record.create()

Comment: @Sunil That's probably because you aren't listening and stil have `record = record.create()` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I think I need to create a separate function where I reset all properties of global object record. That is the safest and sure method it seems. So I would just say resetRecord() instead of record = record.create();

Comment: @ryan - I removed record.create() from all my script, but like I said I get the same error.

Comment: @ryan - I did find your approach does not throw an error after I looked at it in detail. However, it doesn't help me since my aim was to reset the record global variable and it seems record.create() will not always do it. But thanks for all your help.